# Como configurar Apache via linha de comando?

Tags: apache, servidor, terminal, virtualhost

Gostaria de saber se é possível configurar o Apache usando linha de comando (Terminal). Até agora, o máximo que consigo fazer é rodar o comando `apachectl -S` que me retorna as configurações, mas esse valor retornado não é muito amigável. Tem alguma maneira de receber essas infos em uma array/JSON/objeto?

Comment: Poderia criar um script que recebesse o Json, atualizesse a configuração do Apache e executasse o comando para recarregar a configuração.

Comment: Me parece ser a unica saída mesmo. Transformar esse output em Json na mão.